# Is possible to synchronize a particular facebook page onto an android app?

Tags: android, facebook

I was wondering if it is possible to catch feed of a particular facebook page without any authentication and just display all the posts posted by the admin of the page (possibly along with all comments and likes). 
I took a look the facebook developers page but could not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the **public** information of any Facebook page without any permissions.

*However*, You do need to register your app on FB first. They only allow access to their Data from registered apps. It's FB's way of making sure they know who's using which data and how much of it.

You can create a new app at this URL

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Here are links to mobile/web docs for using Facebook's API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Can you give me some more information about how to go about it? Both getting the app registered and also a link to a page where I can learn how to access the information.